# jQuery Sortable only push items downwards

Tags: jquery-ui, grid

I am working on a responsive grid for a formbuilder with jqueryUI's sortable. Now the problem is as following:

[image]

When I exchange the checkbox with the heading beneath the heading pushes up and falls out of the grid. What I want is that the grid only pushes down.

Does anyone know a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have some example code for this, a fiddle maybe ? Because i've made a formbuilder too. I've used a sortable to allow users reorder fields. But if you want a more dynamic approach i would love to help out and share ideas !

Comment: I would certainly like to see what you've made and how you did it. Can you contact me smehow tommorow via Skype or something?

Comment: Sure, i have a working example in asp.net mvc(unfortunately not online), but i am in progress of transferring the backend to php. You can find me on skype : rakhmetovruslan@gmail.com